# How to enable bigtable api (read) on a GCP VM instance using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am using terraform to provision VMs in GCP and I want to enable bigtable api - read.
I am using the scope list below but I cannot find the scope for

[image]

```
service_account = {
  dev = {
    email  = "6xxxxx4-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
    scopes = ["userinfo-email", "compute-ro", "storage-ro", "logging-write", "trace"]
  }
...
}
```

The list in [his link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/compute/instances/set-scopes#--scopes) doesn't seem to be complete ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are the right the alias for

"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigtable.data.readonly" is missing.

As a workaround this will also work

```
  service_account {
    email  = "xxxxxxxxx@xxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigtable.data.readonly"]
  }
```

For Google to update the page please go to feedback at the end of the url you linked and you can notify them there.

Comment: actually i have created it for you https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192762609